# Loading data from dynamic variable inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

first of all I must say that I've already read all the existing similar questions on this topic in SO. But unfortunately none helped me. So, please read the full question before telling it is a duplicate question, as it is not.

### My Situation

I'm using a jQuery script in a wordpress plugin I'm working on. Now I'm using localize script of wordpress to pass variables to the jquery so that I can access it.

Now lets say they are like this:

- example.src1_org
- example.src1_new

and so on...

now inside my jquery I want to do things like this:

```
for (i=1; i<=example.number; i++) {
console.log("example.src" + i + "_org");
console.log("example.src" + i + "_new");
}
```

Now obviously it is returning the string but not the data in console.log. I've also tried `window["example.src" + i + "_org"]` as mentioned in some SO articles, but it didn't worked.

In javascript, generally `eval()` does the work. But I am not sure how to do it in jquery.

Also I've seen in most answers of SO, people are suggesting to use `array`. But in my case, I really don't wanna go that way as it will make my script even more complicated. It is already  complicated enough.

So, it would be really help if any of you can tell me how I can access value from dynamically named variables inside jQuery, without using `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for (i=1; i<=example.number; i++) {
  console.log(example["src" + i + "_org"]);
  console.log(example["src" + i + "_new"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In javascript, generally eval() does the work. But I am not sure how to do it in jquery.

jQuery is not different language, so usage is the same:

```
for (i=1; i<=example.number; i++) {
  console.log(eval("example.src" + i + "_org"));
  console.log(eval("example.src" + i + "_new"));
}
```

Comment: please be carefull when using eval... From MDN : 

Don't use eval needlessly!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: well, I assume it's wordpress which makes so ugly variables like `"example.src" + i + "_org"` - there is no other way to get to variable by it's name

Comment: probably. The comment was more for the user as I consider your answer is correct